# Can I recreate this Flash app's functionality without using Flash?

Tags: jquery, flash, programming-languages, user-interaction

Can I use jQuery or something else to re-create this flash app's functionality?

I haven't messed around with jQuery much, but I feel like the same functionality can be achieved as Flash can.

Are there any other languages or combinations of languages that I could use to replicate the functionality of this site?

[TimeGlider Timeline Creator](http://timeglider.com/app/viewer.php?uid=plamegate)

You have to click the `start` button on the bottom of the first screen in the top left of the page in order to start interacting with the timeline.  If you click the `X` in the top corner, the timeline data won't load.

After clicking `start` clicking on a picture will bring up a caption.  If desired, a link is placed under the caption that opens to a new window.  You can scroll through time and get details on events when they are clicked.

There isn't a lot more to this site, but I want to be able to do something similar using jQuery or another capable language.

Is this possible?  If so, what languages do I need to use in order to replicate the functionality of the flash app on this site?

Comment: Research and Effort will do it. Give it a go and if you run across problems somewhere post the code and the community will help

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Take a look at [Ubuntu's tour](http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/) to see what's possible with just HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript (jQuery).

Comment: @heads5150 - I asked this mainly to avoid a whole lot of work assuming jQuery couldn't cut it. People have seemed to agree that it will suffice and I'll share code when that time comes

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is yes jQuery can handle all the effects shown in there and sticking with it will guarantee cross browser portability, you might throw in a little CSS3 depending on which platforms you are primarily targeting, but this will definitely be a great jQuery project. Happy coding.